# Is f(x,y)=$\frac{x^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{4}} $with f(0,0)=0 continuous in (0,0)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I believe that the function:
f(x,y)=$\frac{x^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{4}}$ is continuous on the point (0,0) but i can't prove it.

I know you have to choose something like $x=cy^{2}$(with c a constant) to prove this but it doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: See #3 in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168531/multivariable-limits and the answers given there.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that we have $f(0,0)=0$. Now note that we have always $|y|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Hence for $(x,y)\not =(0,0)$:
 $$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^4}|y|\leq  1\times \sqrt{x^2+y^2}= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
 This inequality is also true for $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and it is easy to finish.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^4}\right|=|y|\,\left|1-\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4}\right|\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}0$$

since for example, with polar coordinates

$$\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4}=\frac{r^2\sin^4\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta}\xrightarrow[r\to0]{}0$$